# What should I do when get "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" from Paypal

Tags: paypal

How should I handle SUCCESSWITHWARNING when using classic Paypal api?

I searched web for this response but I can't find what it exactly mean and what should I do when I get SUCCESSWITHWARNING response from Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I'd like to share our recent experience with the "SuccessWithWarning" response.

Here was the relevant parts of the paypal response:

```
[ACK] => SuccessWithWarning
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10571
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction approved but with invalid CSC format.
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction was approved. However, the Card Security Code provided had too few, too many, or invalid character types but, as per your account option settings, was not required in the approval process.
```

After looking at the long message, we decided that in this instance, it should be handled as a successful transaction.

In the paypal Fraud prevention documentation they give an example of when this might occur, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/fmf/integration-guide/FMFProgramming/#nvp-example, eg: it's waiting for you to review it. They suggest that you do not discard these transactions, but capture them. Put your order in pending, but do NOT automatically ship them.

So, capture the short and long message, but review the message before shipping.